# How to implement figma's smart animate option in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, widget, flutter-navigation

I designed three onboarding pages in figma which contains information about my app, while wireframing the app, I added smart animate to the three pages[This is the first onboarding page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5khtn.png)
[The second one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdprL.png)
[The third one](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRcrD.png)

The smart animate enables smooth transition from each page to each page

While using flutter, I created 3 different pages for each onboarding pages and added a navigation widget to each button
But the navigation from each page to each page was stacked
I also tried using gesturedetection() onhorizontalswipe still same result
The pages navigate in a stacked way totally different from figma's smart animate option.

Is there anyway I can do this?

I'll appreciate any help
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Am not quite getting it you men like when it's on sliding phase only the center change sthen the below like button as stay put same with indicator now from indicator when page is slide to 2 then the indicator will go wide? is that what you mean smart animate?

Comment: sorry friend, not enough information, visual, code, maybe lot of us not even understand what do you mean. if you could add what the result you want, what the current result, what your code, maybe someone can help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understood,

You want to build an onboarding screen with some animation. But the pages are being stacked.

It is happening because you are navigating to different pages with each button press. That is very bad practice for building an onboarding screen.

You should be using a [PageView](https://medium.com/flutter-community/a-deep-dive-into-pageview-in-flutter-with-custom-transitions-581d9ea6dded) widget that allows you to transit between pages without navigating to them.

If you want to use a plugin that suits you, I would recommend [introduction_screen](https://pub.dev/packages/introduction_screen)

Comment: Thank you very much, this is exactly what I needed. You're blessed